# How to reproduce the password hash created by asp.net MVC default membership

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, hash, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership

I use asp.net MVC 4 default membership system, and the client needs to send a signature includes his hashed password, for authentication.

I need to hash a password just the same as hashed password by server.

```
    private static bool IsAuthenticated(string hashedPassword, string message, string signature)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(hashedPassword))
            return false;

        var verifiedHash = ComputeHash(hashedPassword, message);
        if (signature != null && signature.Equals(verifiedHash))
            return true;

        return false;
    }
```

**So how can I reproduce the hashed password like stored password on the database?**

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here, but it looks very wrong and insecure.  asp.net provides mechanisms to determine whether a user is authenticated or not.  This smells like an XY problem (ie, you ask how to do something silly because you've convinced yourself that doing the silly thing will solve your real problem.  Instead, you should ask about your real problem, which appears to be how you tell whether a user is authenticated or not.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand your question, but there's no need to compare hashed passwords. The membership already has a method for validating a user, you should just use

```
Membership.ValidateUser(username, password)
```

If you are using the membership provider and forms authentication then you can check if the user is already logged in

```
 User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

Comment: I think the intent is how to create the hash outside of .net memership classes alone so it can be done in other systems.

Answer (score 1):

See the **Class System.Web.Helpers.Crypto**
The Method **HashPassword** method.
SimpleMemberShip provider uses this Class for crypto services.

You could just read the entry from DB :-)

for more info see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.crypto%28v=vs.111%29.aspx

BTW, dont forget to consider the SALT.  Does your process require you to combine Pass and salt before hashing ?

Answer (score 0):

.net Membership provider uses a HMACSHA1 hash that's base64 encoded.  You can recreate the same hash using javascript alone on the client side.  The trick is to make sure your password and hash key are the same and to use utf-16le encoding.  Here's the solution using crypto-js.  Not sure why the crypto-js utf-16le function doesn't produce the same result so I am using a different utf function.

```
//not sure why crypt-js's utf16LE function doesn't give the same result
//words = CryptoJS.enc.Utf16LE.parse("test");
//utf16 = CryptoJS.enc.Utf16LE.stringify("test");

function str2rstr_utf16le(input) {
  var output = [],
      i = 0,
      l = input.length;

  for (; l > i; ++i) {
    output[i] = String.fromCharCode(
      input.charCodeAt(i)        & 0xFF,
      (input.charCodeAt(i) >>> 8) & 0xFF
    );
  }

  return output.join('');
}

var pwd = str2rstr_utf16le("test");
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(pwd, pwd);

var encodedPassword = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
```

Comment: Fantastic. I was just about to ask how I can recreate the process in JS for an ASP.Net to Node porting project I'm working on. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Complete method from Crypto.cs @ System.Web.Helpers:

```
/// <summary>Returns an RFC 2898 hash value for the specified password.</summary>
/// <returns>The hash value for <paramref name="password" /> as a base-64-encoded string.</returns>
/// <param name="password">The password to generate a hash value for.</param>
/// <exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException">
/// <paramref name="password" /> is null.</exception>
public static string HashPassword(string password)
{
  if (password == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("password");
  byte[] salt;
  byte[] bytes;
  using (Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfc2898DeriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, 16, 1000))
  {
    salt = rfc2898DeriveBytes.Salt;
    bytes = rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(32);
  }
  byte[] inArray = new byte[49];
  Buffer.BlockCopy((Array) salt, 0, (Array) inArray, 1, 16);
  Buffer.BlockCopy((Array) bytes, 0, (Array) inArray, 17, 32);
  return Convert.ToBase64String(inArray);
}
```